# How to run Loki's port of Simcity 3000 on kubuntu 15.10 with sound on?

Tags: 64-bit, pulseaudio, games, 15.10, oss

So I installed simcity 3000 on kubuntu 15.10 beta 2 successfully with all the patches needed to make it run on such a recent distro. However, I can't get the sound to run.

Since the game still uses oss and I don't have I have '/dev/dsp' (which the game complained about), I installed the 'libpulse0:i386' and 'libpulsedsp:i386' packages. Edited padsp so it points to the rigth 32 bit library, but whenever I run simcity with './padsp ./sc3u.sh' I get:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Running WITH lokicompat libs!
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dynamic-link.h: 62: elf_get_dynamic_info: Assertion `! "bad dynamic tag"' failed!
```

If I run without editing the padsp (i.e. with it pointing to the 64 bit libraries) I get:

```
./sc3u: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However I can do the following:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 43728 Out 13 08:38 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsedsp.so
```

So, I don't know if the game doesn't find the 64 bit library or is incompatible. I think it is the latter, but I can't run with the 32 bit library either...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by installing the package osspd !!!!!!!